# Overlapping labels for short stacked bar chart

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, overlap

Does anyone have an idea how I can avoid that the labels of the stacked bar chart for short bars overlap? The scaling of the x-axis must not change.

[image]

My idea was to write the labels one after the other, so first 25 (blue), then 1 (red).

Another idea was to write the labels alternately below and above the bar.

I could not do both.

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        xbar stacked,
        width=12cm, 
        height=12cm, 
        y=1cm,
        symbolic y coords={RAM-Dump 3, RAM-Dump 2, RAM-Dump 1},
        ytick=data,
        xticklabels={,,},
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 1400,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={horizontal}
        ]
            \addplot coordinates {
            (0,RAM-Dump 3)  (25,RAM-Dump 2) (0,RAM-Dump 1)
            };
            \addplot coordinates {
            (0,RAM-Dump 3)  (1,RAM-Dump 2) (0,RAM-Dump 1)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}}
```

Comment: Please extend your code to a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. This would help us to help you, because we can immediately start testing your code and our ideas.